# Processing thousands of record in c#

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, c#-4.0, rabbitmq, bigdata

I am trying to read thousands of record using c# windows service. I am reading data from RabbitMQ (service broker) topic. My service is able to read thousands of record per sec but issue occurred with processing. I am using Task.Run to process data. Here is the sample code.

```
Task.Run(() => {
//db transactions
});
```

Based on my logging, everything works well. Only issue is with concurrent thread, when i check system log, my service has only 255 (concurrent) thread. Where it supposed to be around 1000+.

What could be blocking for my thread?

Comment: You know that with more threads context switching might reduce overall performance of your system? Can you make better use of existing threads, e.g. by making your workloads async (assuming there is some IO involved)?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for your reply but async is not enough for our processing since we need to process 1000+ data / sec. I am agree that using Task.Run will reduce overall system performance, do you have any other alternative for this?

Comment: A Task is not a Thread... this means that a thread can run more than one task (obiviusly in sequence). Task is supposed to optimize thread use.

Comment: But if you don't have a PC with 1000 core this must not be a problem